# split and store HTML tags into Arraylist

Tags: java, html, split, tags

I'm trying to regenerate the English web page into Sinhala content.Currently i did part of it. When user enter the url it will load the html page of particular webpage and it will appear as line by line with html tags. but now i want to split html tags and content separately and store them in a array list separately.My full code is given below. Can anyone give an answer to split html tags and content separately and store them into array list.

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import  java.lang.String;   

    public class Utils {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         String url;
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Enter the url:");
         url = sc.nextLine();
        try {
            System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "cache.mrt.ac.lk");
             System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "3128");

              //Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(10000).get();

            URL link = new URL("http://www.nlpu.com/NewDesign/NLPU_WhatIsNLP.html");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(newht InputStreamReader(link.openStream()));   
            String inputLine;
            String []arr;
            int count=0;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                // Process each line.
                System.out.println("Line no :"+count++);

                //for(int i=0;i<inputLine.length();i++){
                    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                    list.add(inputLine);
                     System.out.println();

                //}
                for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
                    System.out.println("got: "+list.get(i)); 
                            }
            //  inputLine = inputLine.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", "");
                arr = inputLine.split("<.*?.>");

                for(String ss:arr){
                System.out.print("splitted : "+ss+" ");
                }
                System.out.println();
                 // System.out.println(arr[]);
                //System.out.println(arr[2]);
               //String s1=("මම බත් කමි");
              //list.set(0,s1);
             // System.out.println(""+list);

              }

             in.close();

            }catch (MalformedURLException me) {
            System.out.println(me); 

            } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe);
            }
            }//end main

            private static String inputLine(int i) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           return null;
           }
           }
.
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, you can use a hashmap to store tag and content pair. The HashMap will have string as the key and arraylist as the value.

And for getting the tag, you can use something like inputLine.split(">") and get the first part.
Since there can be many tags with the same name, such as

, you can add multiple values and add them into an arraylist and store them in a hashmap.

And one more thing to add, since you are reading the file line by line, it can happen that sometimes, you can have the ending tag in the next line. for eg...
I dont know how to put code in the editor

In such cases your program will not work. You can rather load the entire file in memory at once by using a RandomAccessFile and then write some algorithm to search for the ending tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will help you. I just edited you code. Make sure its efficient way or not.

```html
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.String;

public class Utils {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the url:");
        // url = sc.nextLine();
        try {
            System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "cache.mrt.ac.lk");
            System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "3128");

            //Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(10000).get();
            URL link = new URL("http://www.nlpu.com/NewDesign/NLPU_WhatIsNLP.html");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(link.openStream()));
            String inputLine;
            String[] arr;
            int count = 0;
            ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                // Process each line.
                // System.out.println("Line no :" + count++);

                //for(int i=0;i<inputLine.length();i++){
                ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add(inputLine);
                //System.out.println();

                //}
                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                    //System.out.println("got: " + list.get(i));

                    //  inputLine = inputLine.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", "");
                    arr = inputLine.split("<.*?.>");

                    for (String ss : arr) {
                        list1.add(ss);
                        //System.out.print("splitted : " + ss + " ");
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                    // System.out.println(arr[]);
                    //System.out.println(arr[2]);
                    //String s1=("මම බත් කමි");
                    //list.set(0,s1);
                    // System.out.println(""+list);

                }

            }
            for (String temp : list1) {

                System.out.println("arrayed : " + temp + " ");
            }
            in.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException me) {
            System.out.println(me);

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe);
        }
    }//end main

    private static String inputLine(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code. Thanks.But I want to parse the html content to our translator tool sentence by sentence and i want to take the translated  Sinhala sentence and replace it to relevant place in the html page. If you have any idea to solve that please post it.Thanks in advance.